# Met a problem when runnning in dreamhost, django + mysql, can someone help look?

Tags: mysql, django, dreamhost

```
ProgrammingError at /account/register/
(1110, "Column 'about' specified twice")Request Method: POST 
Request URL: http: 
Exception Type: ProgrammingError 
Exception Value: (1110, "Column 'about' specified twice") 
Exception Location: /home/temp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36 
Python Executable: /home/temp/bin/python 
Python Version: 2.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a `CREATE TABLE` (or `ALTER TABLE`, etc) which is trying to put two columns both named `about` in the same SQL table -- beyond this, without seeing any of your code, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only learning Python now, and I don't know Django, but my guess is that you have an attribute named 'about' that's been specified twice and needs to be mapped into the database.  Django is resisting your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is close - it is certainly a syntax error returned by MySQL. It's unlikely to be caused by a `CREATE` or `ALTER` though since you're already setup the project and using it over HTTP.

There is one MySQL bug # that produces similar behaviour on syntactically correct statements. But it's very old and it's unlikely that Dreamhost are using such a version of MySQL.

It's more likely to come from an erroneous `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` generated by your models. Cast an eye over the relevant model that defines a field (or two) called `about`.